# Tablet not connecting to any Wi-Fi at home but other devices does

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

My tablet isn't connecting to either of the Wi-Fi at home. The password is correct, and is working for other devices. I have the router of  Belkin, and ZyXEL. Hopefully, this was helpful information

For both Wi-Fi it says "scanning" and then "failed to obtain IP address".

How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: what are your rooter's configurations ? is it set to static ip or DHCP ? how many devices are using that wifi because in some rooters the number of available connection slots is limited to 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Static IP Address to connect a router, then you'll have to long press your wifi name and then advanced options then enter a IP Address manually.